# Why does `switch`, `case` executes the code block even if no match?

Tags: javascript

Considering below JS snippet. It prints 1 and 2 both even if `case: 2` is not a match!
I know, I can put a `break;` to prevent this, but I want to understand the real logic behind this. As this doesn't make sense to execute a block when there is no match.

```js
var a = 1
switch(a){
    case 1:
  console.log(1)
    case 2:
  console.log(2)
}
```

Comment: no [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) ... means no break.

Comment: `switch` uses a *fall-through* logic; it starts executing everything starting at the first matching case. How useful that is is debatable, but that's the way it's been designed since forever in many languages.

Comment: consider if you wanted multiple cases to do the same code block ...

Comment: this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) shows what I mean quite eloquently

Answer (score 4):

The Switch case statement works like a goto. That means that if you match with a label, you jump directly to it. Your code flow is not affected after it.

Comment: That's a neat way of putting it. Kind of a "well-controlled" goto.

Comment: IIRC originally it jumped to the matching memory address and then simply executed everything therein; which means every line of code after the matching `case`. Today this probably doesn't have a whole lot of relevance anymore, but the behaviour still stays.